# Java query db issues. using hibernate and struts2

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting into java here. Fun and frustrating all at the same time :)

I have a simple method called showUsernames():

```
public String showUsernames(){
    TimesheetUserDAO su = new TimesheetUserDAO();
    Session session = su.getSession();
    setUsers(su.findByUsername(_users));
    session.close();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

...however, I am having a time getting just the usernames out of the database. It is possible with the Hibernate DAO to get this correct? I am able to use su.findAll() and return everything.

Any thoughts? Need more code? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The DAO probably executee a request like

```
select u from User u where ...
```

Change the query to

```
select u.name from User u where ...
```

Of course, instead of having a `List<User>` as a result, you'll have a `List<String>`.

This is basic stuff described in the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/). Have you read it?

Also, getting the session from the DAO and closing it manually like this shows a design problem. This should be encapsulated by the service layer or, even better, by the declarative transaction handling.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I'll read over the documentation some more.